# Use strings as parameters for Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, xticks

I want to generate parameters for figures dynamically, pass as arguments to Matplotlib.

Example to illustrate, this works:

```
dict = {'x_tick_fontsize':12 ,'x_tick_weight':'normal','x_tick_rotation':15}
            
plt.xticks(fontsize = dict['x_tick_fontsize']  
           ,weight = dict['x_tick_weight'] 
           ,rotation = dict['x_tick_rotation'])
```

This doesn't, but I want it to:

```
my_params_string = "fontsize = 12, weight ='normal', rotation = 15"
plt.xticks(my_params_string)
```

What can I try next?

Comment: First, don't use `dict` as a variable name!  Second, `plt.xticks(**my_dict)` should work fine.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: @Jody, why do you say don't use `dict`?  It's redundant?

Comment: `dict` is a built-in function to construct a dictionary. By assigning it to a variable, you can't use the built-in anymore. Same goes with `list`, `set`, `tuple`, `sum`, `iter` etc.

Comment: @JodyKlymak if you post as an answer I will accept - it worked. Thx!

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: @halfer I will be a better question asker/member moving forward.

Comment: Thank you! Useful meta references: [Confident asking](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions) and [Removing fluff](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-like-greetings-signatures-thanks-etc-when-editin).